# Sample Appium Framework

Tags: frameworks, appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios, appium-android

This might be a big ask.  Can anyone point to the direction of a to a page or a blog with a sample appium framework that (for iOS and android)  I can take a look at?

Any frameworks that use page mode factory or BDD would be perfect.

Comment: Learn from [appium framework design](http://www.tjmaher.com/2017/05/basic-appium-framework-part-two.html) and [appium framework development](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6tu16kXT9PpePM_yt5Hg-AQqe7_ftH87). This will help you to learn basic about developing appium framework.

Answer (score 1):

I write [AppiumBoot](https://github.com/shigebeyond/AppiumBoot) to use yaml to run Appium auto test. It makes using Appium very simple, and no need to write java or python code.

[demo video](https://www.zhihu.com/zvideo/1542517089130147840)

[demo code](https://github.com/shigebeyond/AppiumBoot/tree/main/example)

some code like

```
# AppiumBoot/example/material/comp5.yml
# home page: click 5th cell
- click_by:
    xpath: /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.FrameLayout[5]/android.widget.LinearLayout # 按钮的xpath路径
  sleep: 1
# second page: click 3th demo
- click_by:
    xpath: /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout[2]
# thirth page: drag and move
  move_track: '360,1100;360,600;800,600;800,1600;100,1600;100,600'
# back to second page: click 4th demo
- back:
  click_by:
    xpath: /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout[4]
  swipe_up:
```

Answer (score 0):

Appium sample project link [here](https://github.com/priyankshah217/AppiumTestAutomation)

Appium with bdd sample project link [here](https://github.com/priyankshah217/AppiumCucumberTest)

Appium with Grid sample project link [here](https://github.com/priyankshah217/AppiumWithGrid)